# jQuery onMouseOver change src in specific ID

Tags: jquery, fade, onmouseover, identifier

Have this markup for products in category page of my online store...

```
Product A
<div id="lateral-thumbnails" class="product-col-left">
    <a class="fancybox lateral-gallery" onMouseOver="return showPic(this);">
        <img src="/images/001.jpg" alt="" />
    </a>
    <a class="fancybox lateral-gallery" onMouseOver="return showPic(this);">
        <img src="/images/002.jpg" alt="" />
    </a>
     ...
</div>

<div id="product-img-box" class="product-img-box">
    <a id="mainframeimage-AAA" href="AAA url">
        <img src="/images/AAA.jpg" alt="" />
    </a>
</div>

Product B
<div id="lateral-thumbnails" class="product-col-left">
    <a class="fancybox lateral-gallery" onMouseOver="return showPic(this);">
        <img src="/images/901.jpg" alt="" />
    </a>
    <a class="fancybox lateral-gallery" onMouseOver="return showPic(this);">
        <img src="/images/902.jpg" alt="" />
    </a>
     ...
</div>

<div id="product-img-box" class="product-img-box">
    <a id="mainframeimage-BBB" href="BBB url">
        <img src="/images/BBB.jpg" alt="" />
    </a>
</div>  

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showPic (thumbs) {
        if (document.getElementById) {

            jQuery('#mainframeimage<?php echo $_product->getId();?>').fadeOut(250);

            setTimeout(function() {
                document.getElementById('mainframeimage<?php echo $_product->getId();?>').src = thumbs.href; 
                jQuery('#mainframeimage<?php echo $_product->getId();?>').fadeIn(250);
            }, 250);

            return false; 

        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

With this javascript code i can change thumbs src's with fade effect to LAST mainframeimage ID processed.

How can i say in javascript language that images 001.jpg and 002.jpg will be placed in mainframeimage-AAA and images 901.jpg and 902.jpg in mainframeimage-BBB?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/czZAv/). I have simplified a little your `mouseover` binding and added some comments to detail the differents steps

Also note that :

- **ids must be unique in the DOM**, you have duplicated ids (`product-img-box`)
- you don't need to do this test `if (document.getElementById)`
- you don't need to return something in your `showPic` function
- the `fadeout()` function supports a callback function, that is to say when fade out is complete, the callback function will be executed so you don't need to use `setTimeout()` to wait before calling `fadeIn()`